# Using JavaScript for scanning wikipedia articles

Tags: javascript, css

I recently saw http://www.histography.io/ - system that uses HTML, CSS and Javascript to scan Wikipedia articles when you hover over a point and grabs the articled and the related youtube video so it can it be displayed to you.

I was exploring the system in the past two hours but can't seem to find the way it fetches the big data that it's in use.

Any pointers to the technique or functions used to fire the events in JS would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of how the videos are being rendered, it looks like there is a large manifest file with video Ids which I presume correspond to youtube video Ids. Refer to: http://www.histography.io/int.js

The main scripts are uglified so it's hard to tell you exactly what each function is doing.
For future reference I'd suggest checking out the network tab of a website in dev-tools to get a better understand of where resources are coming from.

Also when you request a wiki page it is making a request to a sever which takes the following inputs at the endpoint /wiki_page.php:

> link
>
> title
>
> year